# What is the result of casting float +INF, -INF, and NAN to integer in C?

Tags: c, math, standards

Does any standard specifies what should be the output?

For example this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  float a = INFINITY;
  float b = -INFINITY;
  float c = NAN;

  printf("float %f %f %f\n", a, b, c); 
  printf("int %d %d %d\n", (int) a, (int) b, (int) c); 
  printf("uint %u %u %u\n", (unsigned int) a, (unsigned int) b, (unsigned int) c); 
  printf("lint %ld %ld %ld\n", (long int) a, (long int) b, (long int) b); 
  printf("luint %lu %lu %lu\n", (unsigned long int) a, (unsigned long int) b, (unsigned long int) c); 

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled on gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664) Target: i686-apple-darwin10

Outputs:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out 
float inf -inf nan
int -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648
uint 0 0 0
lint -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
luint 0 9223372036854775808 9223372036854775808
```

Which is quite weird. (int)+inf < 0 !?!

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour - what else *could* it be ?

Comment: In Java infinities are cast to the closest value (MAX_VALUE or MIN_VALUE) and NaN is cast to 0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Paul said, it's undefined:

From §6.3.1.4:

> 6.3.1.4 Real ﬂoating and integer
>
> When a ﬁnite value of real ﬂoating type is
>   converted to an integer type other
>   than _Bool, the fractional part is
>   discarded (i.e., the value is
>   truncated toward zero). If the value
>   of the integral part cannot be
>   represented by the integer type, the
>   behavior is undeﬁned.50)

Infinity isn't finite, and the integral part can't be represented in an integral type, so it's undefined.