# How to represent negative infinity and positive infinity for a uint32_t value in C?

Tags: c

How to represent negative infinity and positive infinity for a `uint32_t` value in C?
For a `uint32_t` value in C, how would positive infinity and negative infinity be represented?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make infinity value in C? (especially integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153001/how-to-make-infinity-value-in-c-especially-integer-value)

Comment: Also [Setting an int to Infinity in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8690567), [What is the right way to declare integer INFINITY in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35112322/11082165)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot represent negative numbers with an unsigned integer type like `uint32_t`. You also cannot represent any kind of infinity with integer types in C.

If you are allowed to create and use composite types, you can try a structure like

```
struct extended_int 
{
    int int_value;
    bool is_pos_infty;
    bool is_neg_infty;
};
```

As a commenter below suggested, you can indeed use floats, which have a representation for `inf`, `-inf` and `NaN` (not a number). But converting to and from floating types can lead to loss of precision or even undefined behaviour, so you have to be clear on what type of operations and precision you desire.

Comment: You could mention that converting floating point infinities to an integer type has undefined behavior.

Comment: I am quite confident that converting an infinite FP value to an integer type has undefined behavior, but I cannot find proof of that in the latest C Standard... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77384069/does-assigning-infinite-values-to-integer-types-have-undefined-behavior