# Power function in C gives the same output for large numbers

Tags: c, exponentiation

The [problem statement](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/) requires me to find out the last digit of a^b.
The constraints are that 0 <= a <= 20 and 0 <= b <= 2,147,483,000.

My code works pretty well for numbers like 12^8 or 6^9 or something similar.
But when I move to the large number territory, something like 14^1234 or 17^148713, I am always getting an output of -8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int a;
        long long int b;
        double x, y, res;
        scanf("%d %lld", &a, &b);
        x=(double)a;
        y=(double)b;
        res = pow(x, y);
        int rem;
        rem = (int)res%10;
        printf("%d\n", rem);
    }
    return 0; }
```

What could be the reasons for such a weird output?

Is there no way out apart from storing the big numbers in an array (I guess something like [How to calculate 2 to the power 10000000](/q/39433452))?

Comment: You need a better algorithm - think about the underlying maths a little more, instead of just trying to use brute force.

Comment: Floating point numbers are far to limited in precision for your current solution.

Comment: Hint: read up on [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Comment: You should check the value of `DBL_MAX`, a constant defined in `<floats.h>`, on your system. Odds are, it is many orders of magnitude smaller than the numbers you are trying to deal with.

Comment: As for the -8, once `res` becomes infinite, casting it to `int` yields _undefined behavior_ as explained in [What is the result of casting float +INF, -INF, and NAN to integer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3986795).  On my machine the result of the cast is 0x80000000 or -2,147,483,648.  That number mod 10 is -8.

Comment: This can be done very fast with two mods and a 4x10 table lookup.

Comment: @JoshSanford thanks a lot

Comment: @dbush 4x10 table lookup?

Comment: @KaranSingh See the link above on modular exponentiation.  It follows from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` can hold values up to and including 2^31 - 1 so you basically have an overflow (actually it is causing *Undefined Behaviour* in contrast to overflowing unsigned types).

As already pointed out by @PaulR in comments to your question the general idea is to abuse certain properties of modular exponentiation. In short: you need to keep numbers 'small enough' to *prevent overflow* and to be able to get desired result.

We can use the folowing property: `(a * b) % m == (a % m) * (b % m)`. In code it can look like this:

```
const unsigned int m = 10;  // our modulus
while(t--)
{
    ...                     // read 'a' and 'b'

    unsigned int res = 1;   // last digit of a^b (e.g. res == (a^b % m))
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
    {
        res *= a;           // rising to power i
        res %= m;           // keep res small !
    }

    ...                     // you get desired result
}
```

*Note:* declare `a` and `b` as `unsigned int` - this would be enough for your limits and would prevent unnessesary and unwanted convertions between signed and unsigned.

Comment: Okay I get the logic. Thanks a lot. One more question: is there any approach to make it more efficient. i am getting a TLE error(Time limit exceeded ) on the online judge :/

Comment: @KaranSingh When `b % 2^n == 0` then you can divide `b` by `2^n` then iterate using above loop and finally do `res << n` - effectively rising to the power of 2^n (careful, if `n` is too big it would be a problem, so if `n` is bigger than say 30 do `res << 30` then `res %= m` and then `res << n-30`)

Comment: @KaranSingh take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39433518/7095889) (from the link you noted in question) particularly at the bottom code

Answer (score 0):

See [Integer Overflow](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/integer_overflow.html) for why it is a negative number, as for why the value is always -8, well someone smarter than me will answer that one.